# WMS-C with osmdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid, wms

I´m using the code provided by Stephen Potell for displaying WMS tiles in osmdroid. (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/osmdroid/WtRrQCIfYVk)

At first it seems like the tiles are displayed correct. After adding a my location overlay or an path overlay the tiles or the overlays are displayed incorrect. Assuming the overlays are correct it may seem like the tiles are either one zoom level wrong or the tiles are displayed "one tile off in y-direction".

When enabling multitouchControls in OSMDroid and barely zoom in (just one slight touch) and "hold the zoom" the tiles and overlays are in right location. If going one zoom level in or out the overlays are again positioned wrong.

I have tried playing around with values in WMSMapTileSource but with no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

Ole T.

Comment: is it possible the projection is different that want osmdroid uses?